# React Native: How save data from Api call

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I'm on my first steps in React Native and JS, and have some problems to save data from API.

My Api Call returns a Json like this:

```
    "nomeSquadra": "TeamName",
    "username": "ManagerName",
    "annoFondazione": 2013,
    "budgetAttuale": 100.00,
    "rosa": [
        {
            "idGiocatore": 761,
            "nomeGiocatore": "EMIL",
            "cognomeGiocatore": "AUDERO",
        }
    ],
    "idLega": 3
}
```

At the moment I use the following lines to get the response from the apiCall and save the rosa attribute into the setState.

```
const response = await foApi.get(`api/ApiDetailName`, {headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer`
            }});
        const json = await response.data.rosa;
```

now I need to save the idLega also. And if I do the same like json:

```
const json2 = await response.data.idLega;
```

it doesn't work, and I have no idea why. Is there a better way to get all the attributes from the response?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you console.log the `response.data` please and see if the data is well returned

Comment: I solved with Jimbo's Answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using axios.

```
const response = await foApi.get(`api/ApiDetailName`, {headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer`
        }});

if(response) {
    const { idLega, rosa } = response.data;
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm using axios :) It works! 
Thanks a lot. 

Why does the double assignment not work? 
like the following? 

const idLega, = response.data.idLega;
const rosa  = response.data.rosa;

Comment: you are using await to not async function thats why its not working.

Comment: Ok, make sense ^^  
Thks a lot!